# Add custom field to ModelSerializer output

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to output in my API not only models, but some custom data, before any objects.

`models.py`

```
class ExampleModel(Model):
    example_model_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class ExampleModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = ExampleModel
        exclude = ["id"]
```

`views.py`

```
class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request): 
        examples = ExampleModel.objects.all()
        serializer = ExampleModelSerializer(examples, many=True)
        
        # My custom data which I want to include in this serializer before every thing (on top of it)
        custom_data = "new_york"

        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

I want somehow to include `custom_data` variable in the output (on top of it) so it would looks like this:

```
{
    "custom_data": "new_york",
    "api_output": [
        {
           "example_model_field": "hello world" 
        },
        {
           "example_model_field": "i love you" 
        },
        {
           "example_model_field": "my name is giovanni giorgio" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new custom field to the `ModelSerializer` using a `SerializerMethodField`. This field will look for a method called `get_<fieldname>` run it and populate the field with the result.

```
class ExampleModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    custom_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model  = ExampleModel
        exclude = ["id"]

    def get_custom_data(self, obj):
        return "new_york"
```